# Поддержка тегов в TinyMCE

Tags: wysiwyg, javascript, tinymce, редактор

Здравствуйте. Можно ли в `TinyMCE` включить поддержку `HTML`-тегов? Если напрямую вставлять код, то на выходе получим `<p><br />`, а также `&lt`, `&gt` вместо `<` и `>`, чего не должно быть.

Comment: @Deonis, а где вы нашли эту кнопку?))

Comment: Вы хоть заглядывали на оффсайт? http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php Плюс ко всему, при инициализации укажите не theme : "simple", а theme : "advanced"

Comment: Кстати, @Deonis, вы знаете что он игнорирует тег `<style>`?

Comment: Кстати, не знал и не узнал бы, если б вы не сказали, так как у меня дурная привычка все стили прописывать в отдельном CSS файле ))

Comment: @Deonis, вы все делаете правильно. Просто это мой случай специфичный. Я тоже все стили обычно держу в отдельном CSS файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На панельке есть кнопочка, которая так и называется "*HTML*". Нажимайте её и вставляйте html-код сколько угодно
[image]

Comment: Все, спасибо, разобрался.